# How I convert depth image (3D) using Open3D lib in python

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, depth, open3d

I want convert depth image to a grey-scale point cloud and the point cloud goes to the 3D
object classification

Comment: What have you tried? Otherwise, it would be worthwhile to read the docs: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, here is what you want to do:

1. Create a point cloud using a depth image
2. Have a 3D object detection model that uses your point cloud data?

For number 1, you need to use the following Open3D Method:

```
# You'll need to pass the following min parameters    
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_depth_image(depth_image,                                                        
                                                      intrinisc_cam_parameters, 
                                                      extrinsic_cam_parameters
                                                     )
```

To get a better understanding of what you need to convert depth to pcd, go to this website and look up the method: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html

For #2, it sounds like you're going to need to need to review the instructions for Open3D-ML. These can be found here: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/open3d_ml.html

Comment: Ensure that your depth_image is read in as "depth_image = open3d.io.read_image('/path/to/depth.png')"